# What is Rose's purpose in Get Out?

Tags: character, get-out

We get it, she's a psychopath, does not feel empathy, yet maybe has fun acting and dating (black) people.

But then if she doesn't feel empathy, why does she care about her family and actually brings these black people to the house? If she could actually feel love towards any human being, she'd prefer to keep Chris alive before her family as she finds them old-school and somewhat racist (as she says to Chris).

If she enjoyed acting with Chris for 5 months (and didn't seem tired of it as you see her putting efforts in laughing with him or bringing him snacks etc), why would she just give him away?

Maybe she just likes change and would enjoy moving on to her next victim but again she didn't seem tired of playing with Chris at all.

Comment: An old man and woman cant lure in handpicked black man for their purpose. So Rose was basically baiting black men fitting their profile. And you've quoted Rose as a psychopath - you have your answer there.

Comment: I think the theme of the movie is **not** that the antagonists are psychopaths who don't feel empathy, but rather that they are racists who don't feel empathy for black people but feel empathy for their own family members. I'm actually pretty sure that's the entire point of the movie.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I thought about what @ToddWilcox said but she shows she's not a racist as she clearly spots how wrong her family is when you see them overact ("my man!") to try and hide how much they think there's a fondamental difference between black and white people. But after some thinking my opinion is just that she's just a part of the ritual, which is this mutual agreement like "i bring the blacks and you make us all immortal". As of why she chooses to date them for months instead of simply kidnapping them like her brother, she's just evil and sadistic and enjoys acting.

Comment: She is absolutely racist, she just pretends not to be.

Comment: But none of them are racist: That's the "twist". They even say the only reason they pick black bodies is as a fashion statement. Also, it's improbable that someone who is racist against black people—had a level of antipathy toward them allowed them to kill black people BECAUSE they were black, and not merely because they were a reasonably fit source of bodies—would then be content to walk around as a black person. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Rose was a psychopath or a sociopath.  I think she was  basically an insecure upper middle class girl who,above all else, was compelled to be Mama and Daddy's perfectly polished and obedient little girl.  There were also a couple of times that made me think Rose had been hypnotized by her mother at some point.  Hypnotized in a way that would make Rose do her part of the "job" without any inner conflict to slow the process down.